# Sharepoint 2007 Data view Webpart custom parameters

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2007, web-parts, sharepoint-designer

I'm sort of new to the custom parameters that can be setup on a DataView Webpart.

There are 6 options:
- None
- Control
- Cookie
- Form
- QueryString
- Server Variable

I think that None, Cookie and QueryString speak for themselves and are pretty straightforward.
The issue comes from the other 3. There isn't much documentation as to what they are and how they can be used (or I haven't found it)
I know that there's plenty of tutorials that explain that a dropdown can be a matched to a dataSource and then used as a parameter source 'control'.

If you don't use a datasource it seems that parameter source 'control' isn't the right item to pick as the parameter specified will never be populated with the dropdown values.

If anyone could explain the different parameter sources? Also how would one use checkboxes or a simple input text box to filter a dataview webpart?

Thanks for any tips/help.

ps: here's the link to the dropdown parameter use:
http://sharepointxperiments.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/multiple-filters-on-a-data-view-webpart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other 3 are:

Control: Binds the DataForm(or View)WebPArt to a control somewhere on the page using the following syntax:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="Meal" Location="Control(clStartDate)" DefaultValue="01-01-2010"/>
```

or

```
<ParameterBinding Name="StartDate" Location="Control(clStartDate, SelectedValue)" DefaultValue="01-01-2010"/>
```

Where clStartDate is an ASP.NET Calender Control.

You see that `Control()` takes either 1 or 2 parameters, the second is the name of the property on the control you want to use (i.e. 'Text' or 'SelectedIndex' etc etc.). 
If you leave it empty (like in option 1) it will use the Control's DefaultProperty (as defined by the control itself).

As for the Form option, I've never used it before but I'm guessing it can be used to bind to a value received through a Form POST action.

More info can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/joshuag/archive/2009/04/06/dataformwebpart-parameters-and-parameterbindings.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Colin for the response - I guess I was looking for a full drilldown of what control could bind to.
I've had checkboxes and tried to use 'control' to bind them to without any luck - The most common use of the binding with control is of a dropdown. I'll check out Josh Gaffey's blog for more detail.

Thanks again!